# Expand bit fields to multiple rows (kinda join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-fields, bitflags

let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scheduler](
    [DayOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [time](0) NOT NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
)
```

And some data, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (1, '11:00:00', 'Sunday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (2, '12:00:00', 'Monday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (4, '13:00:00', 'Tuesday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (8, '14:00:00', 'Wednesday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (16, '15:00:00', 'Thursday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (32, '16:00:00', 'Friday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (64, '17:00:00', 'Saturday')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (62, '06:00:00', 'Every business day')
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (127, '08:00:00', 'Every day')
```

How can I produce multiple rows in a SELECT statement if DayOfWeek has more than one flag?

For example, this row:

```
INSERT INTO Scheduler VALUES (62, '06:00:00', 'Every business day')
```

It will be represented in 5 rows in a SELECT statement (one for each day/flag set)

```
DayOfWeek Time             Message
--------- ---------------- ---------------------------
2         06:00:00         Every business day
4         06:00:00         Every business day
8         06:00:00         Every business day
16        06:00:00         Every business day
32        06:00:00         Every business day
```

Running the same query with all the data will give me 19 rows.

- 7 rows - one row for each individual day (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)
- 5 rows - business days (62)
- 7 rows - every day (127)

I'm not sure how can I do this.
I think I can use a cursor to do this, but it is the best option here?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear why you example turns into those 5 rows, can u expand on that?

Comment: Of course, I can...
DayOfWeek = 62
This represents 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 62, respectively: monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + fryday.

So that single row represents 5 days of the week the same task will be run.

Comment: Are these all values you have in your table? Or you can have other values as well?

Comment: My DayOfWeek column is limited to 2^7 (0 ~ 127), being 0 = none and 127 all days (whole week)

Comment: Should 64 in your example equal Saturday?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that... copy and paste issues :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need SQL Server's [Bitwise Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).  This example shows how you can determine which flags are contained in the current value.

```
DECLARE @Mon        INT = 1;
DECLARE @Tue        INT = 2;
DECLARE @Wed        INT = 4;
DECLARE @MonAndTue  INT = 3;    -- Mon (1) and Tue (2) = 3.

SELECT
    @MonAndTue & @Mon,      -- Contains Monday, returns Monday.
    @MonAndTue & @Tue,      -- Contains Tuesday, returns Tuesday.
    @MonAndTue & @Wed       -- Does not contain Wednesday, returns 0.
```

Where possible I'd recommend avoiding bit masking based solutions in SQL Server.  These work great in other languages (C springs to mind).  But SQL works best when each column holds a single value, describing a single item.  Of course you could combined these approaches.  This table design allows you to retain the base 2 keys (great for the frontend) and includes simple bit fields that make filtering in the backend a straightforward task.

```
CREATE TABLE [Day]
(
    DayId       INT PRIMARY KEY,        
    [DayName]   VARCHAR(9),
    IsMonday    BIT,
    IsTuesday   BIT,
    ...
    IsSunday    BIT
)
;
```

**EDIT**

Sorry!  I didn't actually answer your question.  To use the bitwise operations in a join your need syntax long these lines:

```
WITH Scheduler AS
(
    /* Sample data.
     */
    SELECT          
        *
    FROM
        (
            VALUES  
                (1, 'Sunday'),
                (2, 'Monday'),
                (4, 'Tuesday'),
                (8, 'Wednesday'),
                (16, 'Thursday'),
                (32, 'Friday'),
                (64, 'Saturday'),
                (62, 'Every business day'),
                (127, 'Every day')
        ) AS r(DayId, [DayName])
)
/* This join returns every day from s2 that 
 * is contained within the s1 record Every business day.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Scheduler AS s1
        INNER JOIN Scheduler AS s2          ON (s1.DayId & s2.DayId) =     s2.DayId
WHERE
    s1.DayId = 62
;
```

Here S1 is filtered to return *Every business day*.  S2 joins on S1 where a match is found.  This returns Mon, Tue, Wed, etc without returning Sat and Sun.

Comment: Yes, that is it... 
I just need to make a little tweak to exclude the rows that represents more than one day (62 and 127).
WHERE s2.DayId IN (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)

Comment: Do you think it will be easier to apply this same idea if I have multiple columns (one for each day) like you said?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot 62 and 127 would be returned!  It depends where your logic lives.  If the hard work is happening in a frontend then maybe not.  But if you are doing all the heavy lifting in SQL then yes, I'd combine with bit fields for simpler filtering.  Something like *WHERE IsMonday = 1* is easier to read/write/follow than *Day & Day = 1*.